# What are correct callback methods to implement custom toolbar with scrolling and various gesture features?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-custom-view, android-gesture, android-scroll

Implement ToolBar control with custom view regarding:
The goal is to achieve the scrolling features using Xamarin.Android framework and without using `ActionBar` according my business requirement. The required features are left and right swipe, drag tool bar buttons, fling etc.

The scroll should work with more accuracy ex: if the user scrolls (or flings) the tool bar very fast from left to right or right to left, it should directly show the last button.
i.e. similar to `ActionBar` comes with most of the modern Android devices.

What is the correct call-back method to achieve this please

The high level design considerations are: Toolbar button class implements `ImageButton`. The ToolBar button is designed as inner class of ToolBarControl class which is a custom view implementing ViewGroup
I do not want to use `ActionBar` at this moment. 
I want to Override `OnMeasure`, `OnLayout` methods and implement `OnTouch()` and `OnFling()`. Override `OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)`, `OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)`.
Based on the sample code in http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/index.html

code snippet:

```
//To Implement Scrolling
//to watch events by ViewGroup as they are dispatched to child Views
public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    //System.out.println(...)
    Console.WriteLine("OnInterceptTouchEvent");
    Boolean intercept = false;
    ViewConfiguration configuration = ViewConfiguration
                          .Get(Context);
    int mTouchSlop = configuration.ScaledTouchSlop;
    try
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                {
                    int xDiff = (int)Math.Abs(e.GetX() - m_fLastX);
                    if (xDiff > mTouchSlop)
                    {
                        m_nTouchState = c_nTouchStateHorizontalScrolling;
                        m_fLastX = e.GetX();
                    }
                    int yDiff = (int)Math.Abs(e.GetY() - m_fLastY);
                    if (yDiff > mTouchSlop)
                    {
                        m_nTouchState = -1;
                    }
                    if (Math.Abs(xDiff * 2) > Math.Abs(yDiff) && xDiff > mTouchSlop)
                    {
                        intercept = true;
                    }

                    break;
                }

            case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                // Release the drag.
                m_nTouchState = c_nTouchStateRest;
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                m_fLastY = e.GetY();
                m_fLastX = e.GetX();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return intercept;
}

public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{

    //System.out.println(...)

    Console.WriteLine("TB OnTouchEvent");
    try
    {
        float x = e.GetX();
        float y = e.GetY();
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                if (!m_scroller.IsFinished)
                {
                    m_scroller.AbortAnimation();
                }
                m_fLastX = x;
                if (m_scroller.IsFinished)
                {
                    m_nTouchState = c_nTouchStateRest;
                }
                else
                {
                    m_nTouchState = c_nTouchStateHorizontalScrolling;
                }
                break;

            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                int deltaX = (int)(m_fLastX - x);
                m_fLastX = x;
                int scrollX = ScrollX;
                // Scroll to right
                if (deltaX < 0)
                {
                    if (scrollX > 0)
                    {
                        ScrollBy(Math.Max(-scrollX, deltaX), 0);
                    }
                }
                // Scroll to left
                else if (deltaX > 0)
                {
                    // Visible full icons always without empty spaces 
                    int availableToScroll =
                            GetChildAt(ChildCount - 1).Right - scrollX - (display.Width - c_nToolIndent);

                    if (availableToScroll > 0)
                    {
                        ScrollBy(Math.Min(availableToScroll, deltaX), 0);
                    }
                }
                break;
```

Comment: Can some one post code snippet in Java Android?
If the user scrolls (or flings) the buttons of tool bar very fast from left to right or right to left, it should directly show the last button.

Comment: @Cheesebaron,Have you heard any developer using custom view instead of Android Action bar?